# Is constructor calling constructor better approach?

Tags: c#

I have submitted a piece of code for review and I got feedback that it is better practice to have constructor calling constructor instead of set statements duplicates like below:

```
    public GenericFileReader(string fileName)
    {
        _filename = fileName;
        _encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1252");
    }

    public GenericFileReader(string fileName, Encoding encoding)
    {
        _filename = fileName;
        _encoding = encoding;
    }
```

I understand there is way to make constructor call constructor like below:

```
    public GenericFileReader(string fileName) : 
        this(fileName, Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1252"))
    {
    }
    public GenericFileReader(string fileName, Encoding encoding)
    {
        _filename = fileName;
        _encoding = encoding;
    }
```

The second one seems good in terms of reducing number of lines of code. I still not convinced with that second approach is better than earlier one.  Because, calling constructor twice seems costlier operation than setting encoding and filename. Please let me know which approach is better?

Comment: Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.

Comment: All the MVP's I've worked with would say the overloading constructors is better. Only have code in one place - its the reusable and encapsulated part of OOP. The 1st approach is more like procedural programming.

Comment: @KobyDouek No, I don't think this question don't have logical answer.

Comment: @Rajan365 - Its the definition of DRY? You'll find that most programmers are ok with both approaches, however sometimes you come across teams that want consistence, KISS, DRY and etc principles and that's why they said do it the second way.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I prefer to have 1 constructor and have it call a sub-function like below for more complex stuff.

**EDIT: see Zohar's comment on this reply as to why not to overload a constructor.**

**Your best example (IMO)**

I chose this one because when I do not use a central function for use by constructors I prefer the readability of it. But I usually  have my central function as in the bottom example.

```
public GenericFileReader(string filename) 
{
    _filename = filename;
    _encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1252");
}

public GenericFileReader(string filename, Encoding encoding)
{
    _filename = filename;
    _encoding = encoding;
}
```

**For a more complex constructor, but using your sample**

```
public GenericFileReader(string filename)
{
    init(ref filename);
}

public GenericFileReader(string filename, Encoding encoding)
{
    init(ref filename, encoding);
}

private init(ref string filename, Encoding encoding = null)
{
   _filename = filename;
   _encoding = encoding ?? Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1252");
}
```

In the bottom case you could have multiple overloaded constructors all calling the init function in different ways.

Comment: For a public surface of a public class I would have to recommend against using optional arguments.

Comment: any reason why? The second function can be modified to overload without having the optionals present anyway, which is why I included it.

Comment: I like your approach but 1st example given won't work as we can't initialize argument encoding as default value in compile time due to which compiler throws warning. We can have that as null instead!

Comment: because of the way optional arguments works - if some other class is using your constructor without specifying the encoding argument, it's default value gets injected to the compiled assembly of that other class. If it is in a different assembly then your class, any change you want to do to the default value of encoding you will have to recompile both assemblies. That's the main reason I always prefer overloading over optional parameters.

Comment: Ah of course! I didn't think of that, I even had that issue a couple of weeks ago in Xamarin, and went through the process to fix it and didn't even think of that, I will edit my suggestion accordingly. Cheers for the info Zohar!

Comment: Cheers too to RJN for pointing out the compiler warning with encoding.